# Flutter design YoutTube playlist UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in this below screen shot which that same with `YoutTube` playlist, how can i make expanded height for Container which that have `100.0` width?

[image]

```dart
AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/red_glare.jpg',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text('text'),
                      Text('icon'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),),
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

```
Row(
  children: [
    Spacer(),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 100,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('text'),
                Text('icon'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```